# How do I limit the scope of `resolveJsonModule`?

Tags: json, typescript, webpack

I'm working on project that uses Typescript and webpack. I have to import json files, and I have to do it in two ways:

- I have to import project's `package.json` as a module. This has already been implemented previously.
- Have to import some json schemas as resources loadable by url. This is what I'm working on right now.

## Using `package.json` (already implemented)

To import `package.json`, the `tsconfig.json` contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "package.json": ["./package.json"]
    }
  },
}
```

And webpack config has:

```
  /**
   * Determine the array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
   */
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"],
    plugins: [
      new TSConfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: path.join(__dirname, "../../tsconfig.json"),
        logLevel: "info",
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        mainFields: ["browser", "main"],
        baseUrl: tsConfig.baseUrl,
      }),
    ],
  },
```

And this is how `package.json` is used:

```
import packageJson from "package.json";

//...

const release = `${packageJson.version}-${process.platform}`;
```

This is completely type-safe: ts checks that my `package.json` has `version` field. This is working as intended and I don't want to break it.

## Using schema json files (what I'm implementing)

To add support for json schemas, I've added them with filenames matching `.schema.json$` and have added this to webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.schema.json$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
```

And this to a global type declaration file:

```
declare module "*.schema.json" {
  declare const uri: string;
  export default uri;
}
```

I thought that by doing that, Typescript would interpret import such a file as a simple string. I've been following [this example](https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml/blob/main/examples/demo/src/types.d.ts).

However, when I import the schema file in my project:

```
import someSchemaUri from "./schemas/some-name.schema.json";

// ...

uri = someSchemaUri;
```

I still get type error:

> Type '{ ... }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

## Changing `resolveJsonModule`

If I set `resolveJsonModule` option to `false,` this problem goes away, but importing `package.json` from the previous section starts giving an error:

> Module 'package.json' was resolved to 'secret/path/package.json', but '--resolveJsonModule' is not used.

How do I configure my project so that Typescript would interpret these files as a `string`, but at the some don't lose type safety when I import `package.json` from the previous section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there's no way to override json types once `--resolveJsonModule` was set.
May you consider to disable that flag and write types for package.json manually? It's not time-consuming since you use only one `package.json` field.

```
declare module '*.schema.json' {
    const uri: string;
    export default uri;
}

declare module '*package.json' {
    const content: {
        version: string;
    };
    export default content;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I ended up doing when I realised I only use a couple of keys from `package.json` anyway.